# Почему не работает алгоритм нахождения среднего арифметического?

Tags: алгоритм, pascal

Нужно найти среднее арифметическое побочной диагонали матрицы 4*4. Алгоритм вроде правильный, но как то не так считает.

```
for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to n do begin
   if ((j = 4) AND (i = 1)) OR  ((j = 3) AND (i = 2)) OR  ((j = 2) AND (i = 3)) OR  ((j = 1) AND (i = 4)) then

   k := k+1;
   sum := sum + matrix[i,j];
  end;
 end;
```

Ср. арифм. = `sum/k`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему так сложно? А не

```
for i:=1 to n do
begin
    sum := sum + matrix[i,5-i];
end;
```

Это первое. А второе - да, сразу не заметил - вы суммируете все подряд, и только `k` увеличиваете при ваших условиях.

```
for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to n do begin
   if ((j = 4) AND (i = 1)) OR  ((j = 3) AND (i = 2)) OR  ((j = 2) AND (i = 3)) OR  ((j = 1) AND (i = 4)) then
   begin
       k := k+1;
       sum := sum + matrix[i,j];
    end;
  end;
 end;
```

Comment: UPD: Добавил код

Comment: Убрал код, проблема в том кусочке была все таки.

Comment: Согласен, пропущен `begin-end`...